# AutoRenewable subscription in app purchases didn't have free trial

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, appledoc

As per In App Purchases Guide in apple's developer resources, it clearly says that we can offer free trial option.
[image: In App Purchases Guide Table 12-5 from Apple Developer Docs.]

But I couldn't able to see it anywhere when I am setting in App purchases in iTunesConnect. Are they still offering that? Where can I find it?

Here is the screen shot of what I see in my iTunesConnect
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iTunes Connect you will find it here

```
App > Manage In App Purchases > Subscription Basic > 1 Month >  Offer a free trial?
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, I couldn't able find that. Only thing I found when setting price tier is "Offer a marketing opt-in incentive?" I could provide screenshot, but I don't know how to do it in comments though.

Comment: BTW, I found this link in apple's forum when  I was searching for this issue https://devforums.apple.com/message/792887#792887 where they discuss the same thing.

Comment: Sound like you need a screenshot. Here you go.

Comment: Please check the screen shot attached to my question. How come I didn't had that in mine? My in-app purchases are Auto-Renewal Subscription in-app purchases. Is yours different? Also mine is not a newsstand application.

Comment: My application is a newsstand application. Maybe that's the difference?

Comment: Is there any way to specify free trial period duration other than 7 days or 1 month? I searched Apple documentation, but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: @AndrewPolunin seems like those are the only options. sadface.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're app is NOT a newstand application.